# How to select the odd-child in any sequence inside the body?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, less

I have an html structure something like this.[image]

How can i achieve the background-color to be red or blue based on their sequence in the body?

Comment: You can't with CSS. You need Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```js
$(".my-class").filter(":odd").css("background","red");
$(".my-class").filter(":even").css("background","blue");
```

```css
  .common { padding: 20px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="my-class common"></section>

    <div class="">
        <section class="my-class common"></section>
    </div>

    <div class="">
        <div>
            <section class="my-class common"></section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="my-class common"></section>
```

Comment: With this code if you add more `div` the sequence is not complied: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/xL4qsvsx/3/

Comment: @blonfu He said the order inside the body, not the order of the parent div inside the body.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible with css selectors. Go with JavaScript:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.my-class'), function(c, i){
  c.style.backgroundColor = i%2 === 0 ? "tomato" : "skyblue";
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9x1gp54/1/)**

Using jQuery:

```
$('.my-class:even').css({'background-color': 'tomato'});
$('.my-class:odd').css({'background-color': 'skyblue'});
```

Or better would be to add classes, using JavaScript/jQuery, like `my-class--odd` and `my-class--even` which holds the styles.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only with CSS using `nth-child` and direct child selectors:

```css
body > div,
body > section,
body > section > div {
  border: solid 1px green;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}

body > .my-class:nth-child(odd),
body > :nth-child(odd) .my-class {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}

body > .my-class:nth-child(even),
body > :nth-child(even) .my-class {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">.my-class (first)</div>
<div>div
  <div class="my-class">.my-class (second)</div>
</div>
<section>section
  <div>div
    <div class="my-class">.my-class (third)</div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="my-class">.my-class (fourth)</div>
```